# Swift 3: ¿cómo guardar y recuperar una imagen con coredata con y pegarla en imageview?

Tags: swift3

```
 func guardarDatos(){

    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Usuarios> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Usuarios")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    if let container = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer {
    let context = container.viewContext
self.fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        self.fetchResultController.delegate = self
        do{
           try fetchResultController.performFetch()
            usuario = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            self.usuario = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects!
            print("Datos en COREDATA")
        }catch{

            print("Error")
        }
       }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto te debería funcionar:

```
    do{
        try fetchResultController.performFetch() 
        usuario = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        self.usuario = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects!

        // Agregado
        if let photoinData = usuario.value(forKey: "photo") as? UIImage {
            imageView.image = photoinData
        }
        //
        print("Datos en COREDATA")
```